# cancel ask question

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I find that often asking a question brings better search results as shown [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268318/why-is-the-this-question-might-exist-search-better-than-the-normal-search)

In this case is it possible to have a cancel button to asking a question? because once you start asking a question, better results are displayed and in that case asking a question is no longer needed.

Might stop duplicate questions.

Comment: Nothing forces you to post the question. Just close the browser tab to cancel.

Comment: I agree with the basic observation here, though. The search results inside the ask question dialog tend to be vastly better than those from normal search.

Answer (score 9):

I understand where you're coming from but there's really no need. There are several ways to cancel a question:

1. Use the browser's back button.
2. Simply navigate to another page.
3. Use the "discard" link that appears when a draft of the question is saved.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the discard button is the one that cancels the process.  The other techniques may result in saving the draft and showing it next time you click "Ask Question", or leave the partially written question around in some other form.

Comment: I don't see the discard button? Using the back button is hardly user friendly, and naviagting away always keeps my question when I return another time. Cant upload a pic to comment otherwise would have shown you what i mean.