# Search vs Asking Question (Newbies)

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, search

This is a similar to question [Why is the “this question might exist” search better than the normal search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268318/why-is-the-this-question-might-exist-search-better-than-the-normal-search) but I think my point is fundamentally different.

My point is that it doesn't appear obvious (it didn't appear obvious to me, as a new user) that I might easily find the answer to my question by starting the "ask question" process and typing in my question.

What happened to me is I spent about 30-60 minutes, using Google and Stack Overflow search, trying to find an answer to a question.  (I ended up with many hits that didn't give me an answer I needed and reading the "close but no cigar hits" took some time.)

Deciding that I had given it a good effort, I decided to ask and as I asked, the answer popped up.

My suggestion is to tell new users, ideally during the tour, that starting the "ask question" may lead to rapid success.

Comment: Consider that the title you used for your question is probably a better search term to use on Google and Stack Overflow search than whatever else you have attempted?

Comment: Oded, after I had the success, I tried that in both the Stack Overflow search and the Google search.  The Google search worked but the Stack Overflow search didn't.  Unfortunately, I asked my question last Wednesday or Thursday and have forgotten the exact search string.  In any event, I've learned my lesson but the new users following me haven't; many of them don't even know Stack Overflow exists, yet.  What I'm made was an educational suggestion.  (Among other things, I'm a teacher.)

Comment: The point I was trying (very poorly) to make was that the searches (Google/Stack Overflow/Ask a Question) are all very different - there is no guarantee one of them is _better_ than the others.

Comment: Oded, fair enough.

Comment: I got a similar feeling, and I concluded that when asking a new question the search engine takes into account also the tags you have chosen, and that could lead to different results.