# Including "Questions that may already have your answer" and "Similar questions" algorithms in the general search

Tags: feature-request, search

Sometimes, when I have a question and I try to search for an answer within the existing set of questions and answers in Stack Overflow, by typing it into the search box at the top of the page, for example `force preload images hidden with display none`, no results are found; not even partial matches.

However, when I then open a new question and type in the same text for the question title, I get a number of questions whose answers may or may not help me, but at least they give me the option of checking and I often learn new things in the process.

And then there is the "Similar Questions" panel on the right, often showing a set of questions seemingly different from the set previously described. In both cases, the results are more useful than the "no results found" in the general search box.

I realise that the general search uses a different algorithm which may, under other circumstances, yield useful results, but it sometimes yields no results at all, which is not completely helpful.

Couldn't the general search mechanism include the other two, at least as a fallback when its own algorithm fails to find any results?

This [was discussed several years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268318/why-is-the-this-question-might-exist-search-better-than-the-normal-search), which I have only noticed when this question was almost written.

UPDATE

I'm not sure I have phrased this question correctly. I was trying to ask about the consolidation of multiple search mechanisms, all internal to the platform, in order to improve the user experience. However, I am noticing how people seem to be reading it as a question about whether I should or shouldn't use an external search tool to find answers to my questions.

I already knew that Google searches are far superior to Stack Overflow's general search feature; comments suggesting that I use Google, while very much appreciated, are neither providing me with any new information nor, unfortunately, answering the question I posed. I still don't know why the general search feature at Stack Overflow cannot include the algorithms used in the "Questions that may already have an answer" and the "Similar Questions" features, as a fallback when its own algorithm finds nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are doing it wrong.  The search engine URL is google.com

Comment: @HansPassant Why not remove the general search box, then?

Comment: _@CarvoLoco_ There are still cases it's useful. Otherwise I'm with @Hans.

Comment: IMHO, if a feature announces itself as a search but it cannot find a single result when other search mechanisms (both internal and external to the site) can find multiple, then the feature is unintuitive if not broken. At that point, at least two courses of action are possible: 1) fix it making the platform more intuitive to use, or 2) establish a tedious ritual upon where veteran users must keep telling novices to use an external search tool. Do you guys really think [2] is the most sensible course of action? I am surprised.

Comment: Yeah, if we actually had to tell every single novice to just use Google that wouldn't be sensible. But since 99% of them do that anyway...

Comment: Just to note: if you want to get the same results as the possible duplicate check or the related questions panel, do a **title:** filter search. Google will always be the king of contextualising a keyword search query, but the site search excels at doing [filter searches](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). Quite an invaluable tool.