# Can you get the main search bar to mimic the ask question suggestion search?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, search

**Is there way to get the main search bar to *exactly* mimic the ask question search, by adding an extra term or symbol?** I didn't pick up on anything in the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

---

My example search term is `networks.net.ipam.config must be a list` (related to Docker).

When typed into the main search it got 0 results. In contrast, when typed into the ask question title I get results with similar questions containing the (simple) answer.

One of the commenters [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268753/1461850) suggests `title: <search term>` in the main search bar but, for my case, this didn't work.

---

If there isn't a way to mimic the ask question search, I propose that there should be:

Maybe `aq: <search term>` (for ask question). Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

### Remove names from your search

Evidently, the reason why the Ask Question page shows results is because it's ignoring "networks.net.ipam.config" entirely. Regular search expects all your search terms to be present in the post. Searching for "must be a list" in titles or in [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) returns the questions you're looking for.

I believe "networks.net.ipam.config" is the name of a key in YAML (with each dot representing a new level of nesting), but what matters is that it varies. There are plenty of lists in other YAML files (or maybe even the file you're in) with other names.

### There's no other way to use the Ask Question search

Regular site search doesn't ever work like that. You have to be signed in, and you can't be question banned, and you have to pretend like you're [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). There's no other way.

There's really old requests to change that, however: [Why is the "this question might exist" search better than the normal search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268318/6083675)

Comment: Thanks Laurel. The point is that the query yields useful response in one search box and none in the other; I wasn't looking for an answer to the search query here! Also, I was aware of the old request (linked in the question).

Comment: Further, being signed in shouldn't be an impediment. Surely a conditional check like `search_query_chars[0..2] == 'aq:'` would be straightforward, Then redirect search to ask question mode.

Comment: I mean, sure, but laurel here is describing how it *currently* works.

Comment: @KevinB fair; perhaps my comments were a little abrupt.